# How can I make code more reactive; Remove if's, check for empty and do intermediate logging

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am considering, how may I rewrite this code in more reactive way (without if's, throw Exceptions in intermediate steps etc., and best practice for logging intermediate results)

```
        return identityRepository.findByDeviceIdAndToken(
                deviceId,
                authToken
        ).doOnSuccess(identity -> {
            if (identity == null) {
                log.info(
                        "Pair Auth-Token: {} and Device-ID: {} not found",
                        authToken,
                        deviceId
                );
            }
        })
                .map(MyPrincipal::new)
                .map(
                        principal -> {
                            if (!principal.isCredentialsNonExpired()) {
                                throw new CredentialsExpiredException();
                            }
                            return 
                                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                                            principal,
                                            null,
                                            Collections.emptyList()
                                    )
                            ;
                        }
                )
                .flatMap(this.authenticationManager::authenticate)
                .map(SecurityContextImpl::new);
```

Comment: do you really need the null check? you can return an optional

Comment: but how it helps actually simplify ?

Comment: i find optionals better than nulls, nulls can throw NullPointerexceptions and other strange behaviour.

Comment: @AlexFaster, Which version of java are you using ? . Is it 9+ ?

Comment: @AjitSoman yes, java 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) to eliminate `if` condition from your code. There are total 2 if condition in your code.
Lets first remove `if` from `doOnSuccess` method

```
.doOnSuccess(identity -> {
 if (identity == null) {
  log.info(
   "Pair Auth-Token: {} and Device-ID: {} not found",
   authToken,
   deviceId
  );
 }
})
```

You can use [ifPresentOrElse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresentOrElse-java.util.function.Consumer-java.lang.Runnable-) to remove if condition. It was introduced in java 9:

```
.doOnSuccess(identity -> Optional.ofNullable(identity)
 .ifPresentOrElse(
  val -> {},
  () -> log.info(
   "Pair Auth-Token: {} and Device-ID: {} not found",
   authToken,
   deviceId)
 )
)
```

The second `if` condition is in `map` method

```
.map(principal -> {
    if (!principal.isCredentialsNonExpired()) {
        throw new CredentialsExpiredException();
    }
    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, null, Collections.emptyList());
})
```

In above code, You are throwing some exception based on a condition. You can use [filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) along with [orElseThrow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow-java.util.function.Supplier-) to throw exception if Optional has become empty due to filter:

```
.map(principal -> Optional.of(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, null, Collections.emptyList()))
        .filter(token -> token.getPrincipal().isCredentialsNonExpired())
        .orElseThrow(CredentialsExpiredException::new))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change map logic in this way:

```
return identityRepository.findByDeviceIdAndToken(
                deviceId,
                authToken
        ).doOnSuccess(identity -> {
            if (identity == null) {
                log.info(
                        "Pair Auth-Token: {} and Device-ID: {} not found",
                        authToken,
                        deviceId
                );
            }
        })
                .map(MyPrincipal::new)
                .filter(principal -> principal.isCredentialsNonExpired())
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new CredentialsExpiredException()))
                .map(x -> new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                                principal,
                                null,
                                Collections.emptyList()
                        )
                )
                .flatMap(this.authenticationManager::authenticate)
                .map(SecurityContextImpl::new);
```

Comment: thank u, it is much better, but do u have any thoughts about 'log' part?